# Is Bluemix HIPAA compliant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, standards-compliance, hipaa

Is [IBM Bluemix](http://www.bluemix.net) a HIPAA compliant platform?

If yes, please provide me with a link to the official documents stating that.

If not when is it expected to be?

Comment: The question is off-topic for SO. BTW: You can read about the Bluemix compliance on these pages: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/security/index.html#compliance and http://www.softlayer.com/compliance where HIPAA is listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 01**

From the [IBM Bluemix Security](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/security/index.html#compliance) on December/2/2016:

> The Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA),
>   enacted by the US Congress in 1996, protects health insurance coverage
>   for employees after job loss. HIPAA is regulated and enforced by the
>   Office of Civil Rights and Department of Health and Human Services in
>   the US. HIPAA encompasses regulations from the 1996 act, as well as
>   privacy requirements from the Health Information Technology for
>   Economic and Clinical Health (HITECH) Act of 2009. Bluemix meets all
>   of the requirements for HIPAA on the data center or service provider
>   side.

So it seems Bluemix is currently compliant with HIPPA.

---

From [IBM DW Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/27054/is-bluemix-hipaa-compliant.html) on January/23/2016:

> <s>Bluemix is not currently HIPAA compliant. Bluemix is currently
>   undertaking an exercise to document and measure ourselves against the
>   complete spectrum of regulatory compliances and tackle those in an
>   order based on market priority.</s>

<s>It does not look like there is a decelerated date for doing this just yet.</s>

Keep an eye on the [Bluemix Compliance page](http://ng.bluemix.net/docs/security/index.html#compliance) as well as [Softlayer Compliance page](http://softlayer.com/compliance).

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed the Bluemix standards compliance site and it does not claim any HIPAA support.
So no currently they doe not support HIPAA.

Answer (score 2):

Nop. Bluemix is not claiming support for HIPAA standards.

Answer (score 2):

From the [IBM Bluemix security web page](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/security/index.html#compliance) (compliance section):

> Bluemix meets all of the requirements for HIPAA on the data center or
>   service provider side.

Link: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/security/index.html#compliance